# Querying with Dax: The syntax for '(' is incorrect

Tags: c#, dax, adomd.net

I am trying to obtain the average of a column value for a subset of rows based on a filter of another column.

```
var mdX = @"CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Column1]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Column2] = 'bla'))";

using (AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand(mdX, connection))
{
      var result = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

but I get a unhelpful error message:

> Query (1, 10) The syntax for '(' is incorrect. (CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Column1]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Column2] = 'bla'))).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, a DAX expression starts with `something =` but since you just want the result, try adding `EVALUATE` to the beginning.

```
"EVALUATE CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Column1]),FILTER('Table','Table'[Column2] = 'bla'))"
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error: Query (1, 116) Cannot find table 'bla'.

Comment: Try double quotes. Single quotes make it think you're referring to a table.